# Deserialize mutable (primitive/object) JSON property to object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Given a JSON object having a mutable property (e.g. *label*) which can be either primitive value (e.g. string) or an object. A hypothetical use-case could be a wrapper for pluralized translation of a label:

```
{
   "label": "User name"
}
```

or

```
{
   "label": {
       "one": "A label",
       "other": "The labels"
   }
}
```

The goal is to bring [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) deserialization always return a fixed structure on the Java-side. Thus, if a primitive value is given it is always translated to a certain property (e.g. *other*) of the target POJO, i.e.:

```
public class Translations {
   @JsonDeserialize(using = PluralizedTranslationDeserializer.class)
   public PluralizedTranslation label;
}

public class PluralizedTranslation {
   public String one;
   public String other;  // used as default fields for primitive value
}
```

Currently the issue is solved by using a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) which checks whether the property is primitive or not:

```
public class PluralizedTranslationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public PluralizedTranslation deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        PluralizedTranslation translation;

        if (node.isTextual()) {
            translation = new PluralizedTranslation();
            translation.other = node.asText();
        } else {
            translation = oc.treeToValue(node, PluralizedTranslation.class);
        }

        return translation;
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant approach for handling mutable JSON properties without having a decoder which operates on node level?

Comment: This question has nothing about mutability. You've just have a property and want to deserialize it in some way.

Comment: @Miha_x64 I've described the property value as mutable because the type of its value has ["liability or tendency to change"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mutability). Sorry for misleading adjective, the question is of course not about (Java) object mutability.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the `label` setter more generic and add some logic handling the two cases.

```
public class Translations {
    // Fields omitted.

    @JsonProperty("label")
    public void setLabel(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof String) {
            // Handle the first case
        } else if (o instanceof Map) {
            // Handle the second case
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported");
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternative solution**, which places the factory method inside the `PluralizedTranslation` class, leaving the `Translations` class unaffected:

```
public class PluralizedTranslation {
    public String one;
    public String other;  // used as default fields for primitive value

    @JsonCreator
    private PluralizedTranslation(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Map) {
            Map map = (Map) obj;
            one = (String) map.get("one");
            other = (String) map.get("other");
        } else if (obj instanceof String) {
            other = (String) obj;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the constructor can be marked as `private` to prevent unintended usage.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Indeed, this solution eliminates the `JsonDeserializer`. Unfortunately, it also moves the `PluralizedTranslation` creation logic into the POJO. Hence, it will get dependencies to some factories and/or an `ObjectMapper` which is not really pretty. Further, having `private` fields (which were omitted in the question for simplicity) we will need to add additional check for `o instance PluralizedTranslation`. Altogether, this alternative solution does not look much cleaner to me...

Comment: @dim: I can't completely follow your objections, but I'll try to answer them. A factory of some kind is needed under all circumstances. I would argue that putting it in the class itself makes it easier to understand what happens. I don't understand the need for an `o instanceof PluralizedTranslation`. In both cases an instance of `PluralizedTranslation` is created, so that would be the only thing a user of the class would have to work with. I'm adding another approach I came up with, which places the creation of `PluralizedTranslation` in a private constructor, which I find rather elegant.

Comment: I agree that your solution is pretty understandable. My first objection was related to the fact, that `setLabel` should be able to accept a valid instance of `PluralizedTranslation` (which currently would cause `RuntimeException`) but it is a no-brainer. 2nd: it is reasonable to use the `ObjectMapper` instead of the the hand-made mapping, which means that it has to be injected into POJO. This is where I'm not comfortable with. However, your suggestions are valid for the given simple case but I was more searching for a magic `@JsonDefaultValue` annotation ;).